# Internal redirection: Serve “/site” as “/” and “/sub/blog” as “/blog”

Tags: htaccess, shared-hosting

I have a website with a shared hoster. There are a few things that I have there, like main site, Piwik, a blog and other standalone things.

Right now I have the following structure:

- `~/subs/www` gets served as `example.org` and `www.example.org`
- `~/subs/blog` gets served as `blog.example.org`
- `~/subs/app/piwik` gets served as `app.example.org/piwik`
- `~/subs/app/foo` gets served as `app.example.org/foo`

This is a all nice, I have separate cookies for the different applications. However, I would need a wildcard TLS certificate in order to get everything encrypted. Especially since Piwik is included in the main page, it must also be served over a secure connection. The provider wants 10 EUR/month for the wildcard certificate.

Now they offer *one* free certificate which I have issued for `example.org` and getting `www.example.org` for free. In consequence I would have to serve everything from `example.org` in order to get consistent TLS.

From a user standpoint, I would like to have the following URLs:

- `/` is the main site
- `/blog` is the blog
- `/app/piwik` points to the Piwik installation
- `/app/foo` points to some other stand-alone application

I do like the directory structure on the server, especially since I can just `rsync --delete` into the `~/subs/www` directory and automatically prune files that I have deleted on disk. If I would upload the files such that they get served correctly, I would not do this any more.

So I would like to do this:

- `~/subs/www` is served at `example.org/`
- `~/subs/blog` is served at `example.org/blog`
- `~/subs/app/piwik` is served at `example.org/app/piwik`

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10953615/invisibly-rewriting-root-to-subdirectory-using-mod-rewrite-ajaxplorer) I gathered that the following `.htaccess` should do the trick:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subs/
RewriteRule ^blog(.*) /subs/blog$1 [L]
```

However, when I request `example.com/blog` in my browser, I get *redirected* to `example.com/subs/blog`. I don't want to redirect, I want to do this mapping in the background such that the visitor will never see the URL fragment `/subs/`.

The shared hoster is Domain Factory, I can put in `.htaccess` files but I cannot alter any configuration files that need `root` access to the system.

How can achieve this?

Comment: The document root is `~/subs/www` for the main site and the others are configured as separate virtual hosts.

Comment: Can you edit your virtual host configuration files?   You could do this with `Alias` directives, but they can only be used in the main conf files, not in `.htaccess`.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller: I have looked into the admin panel, and I cannot find anything. I think I am limited to `.htaccess`.

Comment: Then your only solution is probably to move the directories.

Comment: If I was to use symlinks, I'd have to symlink every top-level file and directory from the “subdomains”, right?

Answer (score 1):

From what i gather, try this :

```
RewriteRule ^blog$ /subs/blog [L]
```

and save it in your roots (www) folder's `.htaccess`

But i believe that your best bet would be to do a direct redirection such as

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Redirect ~/subs/blog/ http://www.yourdomain.com/blog/$1
```

Comment: using this technique will mask the /subs/ folder from the url. Check out both these sites links and see them in action http://miyustory.com and http://miyustory.com/v5/index.php both these links are identical however the first one masks the entire url to point it to the main page and the other is the actual link that i try to keep hidden this was done using the technique i posted as your answer. Try it

Comment: Please do *not* use this site to promote yours

Comment: Please note that with these links, I am not trying to promote anything. It just happens to be information about this topic in question. Very useful and informative information about this topic can be located at those links